# Looking for a simple example to fire "make" from Maven2

Tags: maven-2, makefile

This is a transitional solution.
I don't want to write my own plugin.
I have too many small, scattered makefiles to convert to pom.xml all at once.
I'm trying to move to Maven2 as a skunkworks project and gradually migrage new + changing code to pom.xml files.

The arch-independent C/C++ solutions are not needed - plus the Makefile run multiple scripts to generate code before compilation.

Any pointers to extending "mvn deploy" to handle "make deploy" would be great.

Thanks
AJ

Answer (score 1):

You should check Codehaus' related [CBUILDS](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cbuild-parent/index.html) project. It may help you with downloading dependencies, unpacking, patching, and invoking `make`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to why you're moving towards maven with C projects, but if I were you, I'd look at gmaven-plugin to execute an [inline groovy script](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code#ExecutingGroovyCode-ExecuteanInlineGroovyScript) to invoke what you need.  Then, if you want to create a plugin later, it should be easy to migrate to one.